# JSON MySQL 5.7 query

Tags: mysql, json

I have innodb table with a column in JSON format

My table products:

```
id_products      int
name_products    varchar --> fx-6350<br>
feature_products json    --> {"cache":{"l1":"128k","l2":"6Mb","l3":"8Mb"},"frequency":"3.9GHz","socket":am3+"}
```

How can I make a query with result "frequency" and "3.9GHz" and query for everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want something like this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(feature_products, "$.frequency") = '3.99GHz';
```

I created a table "products" - note that the last record corresponds to the one we want.

```
SELECT * FROM products;

id_products name_products   feature_products
1   blah    {"cache": {"l1": "128k", "l2": "6Mb"}, "socket": "am3+", "frequency": "3.97GHz"}
1   blah2   {"cache": {"l1": "128k", "l2": "6Mb"}, "socket": "am3+", "frequency": "4.7GHz"}
1   result  {"cache": {"l1": "128k", "l2": "6Mb"}, "socket": "am3+", "frequency": "3.99GHz}
```

Running the query above

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(feature_products, "$.frequency") = '3.99GHz';
```

gives:

```
id_products name_products   feature_products
1       result      {"cache": {"l1": "128k", "l2": "6Mb"}, "socket": "am3+", "frequency": "3.99GHz"}"
```

Which, as we can see, is what was required -  `result "frequency" and "3.9GHz" and query for everything`

I found [this reference](https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2015/sites/default/files/slides/MySQL_5_7_JSON_PerconaLive2015.pdf) helpful. And, if all else fails, one can always consult the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) :-). Also, the MySQL server team [blog](http://mysqlserverteam.com/json-labs-release-json-functions-part-1-manipulation-json-data/) was useful.

Comment: For performance it should be possible to create a virtual indexed column from that JSON property - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/generated-column-index-optimizations.html.

Comment: Wow!!!! Thank you so much for help me!! :)